# Gnuplot datafile Multiple separator

Tags: sed, gnuplot

I have a data file which has the following arrangement :

```
#REY2_0 REY1_0  alpha1  alpha2   omega
1000    10000   (-3,0)  (1,0)   (-0.21259151,-0.17763971)
```

I have to use the REY2_0, REY1_0 and the second element of omega i.e -0.17763971 in this case. How would I be able to use this in splot ? Can I add multiple separators to gnuplot and then use the resulting columns ? How is this done ? Can I change the data file using sed?

Edit :
The sample output would be :

```
#REY2_0 REY1_0  alpha1  alpha2   omega
1000    10000     -3       0      1       0      -0.21259151      -0.17763971
```

Comment: Please post sample output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `sed`,

```
sed 's/[(,)]/\t/g' yourfile
```

If you want to made the changes in file,

```
sed -i.bak 's/[(,)]/\t/g' yourfile
```

To get proper formatted output,

```
sed 's/[(,)]/\t/g' yourfile | column -t > newupdatedfile
```

It is working for your sample input file.